# Is there a way to write shellcode for sendfile that does not use syscall instruction directly?

Tags: x86-64, system-calls, shellcode

I'm working on a ctf-like challenge and it is filtering my shellcode to make sure I don't have the hex value encodings of the syscall, sysenter and int instructions 0x0f05 0x0f34 and 0x80cd respectively. Basically I have a shellcode that can open a file but it includes the syscall instruction. Any help with understanding how to manipulate it so I can still make syscalls without explicitly putting the sequence 0x0f05 in my shellcode.

```
lea rdi, _string[rip]
xor rsi, rsi
xor rax, rax
mov al, 2
syscall
```

I'm not necessarily looking for an exact answer but just looking for some help understanding some possible ways to manipulate the program into making a syscall at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can already inject code, you presumably have your code in a page with write+exec permission so you could make it self-modifying, and store the bytes for a `syscall` instruction one at a time (so they aren't filtered as part of an imm16).

Or even easier, start with `0e 05 ...` in memory, and use `inc  byte ptr  syscall_location[rip]` to modify it to `0f 05 ...`.  A RIP-relative addressing mode means you don't need to know the address of the byte you want to modify, just it's relative distance (which the assembler will calculate for you).  You might need to jump forward so the `rel32` is negative and doesn't have any zero bytes.  Or put the `syscall` instruction first and jump back to it.

As Sinkmanu points out, you might find a `syscall` instruction somewhere in the process's memory map, in which case techniques like you'd use for ret2reg might work.

But shared library code will tend to be ASLRed relative to the executable, and unless there's a PLT stub for `sendfile` in the main executable you won't have the dynamic linker's help in finding it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the program which you are exploiting has loaded shared libraries containing a `syscall` instruction (for example `libc`), you can make a shellcode that jumps there.  Or even jump straight to the `sendfile` wrapper function in glibc, passing it args in registers.

Another way, you can use alternative syscalls like read and sockets syscalls.